# Change the Part selection in RCP Application when Button click in different Part

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

In Eclipse RCP Application UI design of my project will be as below:

```
PartSashContainer->PartStack->Part1, Part2,Part3.,Part4,Part5
                 |
                 ->PartStack->Part6
```

Part6 contains the button. If button click in Part6 should set the selection to Part1.

Can you please provide how to achieve the Part selection from different Part.

[image: UI Reference]

Comment: Is this an e4 RCP (using an Application.e4xmi) or a 3.x compatibility RCP?

Comment: Yes this is E4 RCP Application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `EPartService` `showPart` method:

```java
@Inject
EPartService partService;

...

partService.showPart("part id", PartState.ACTIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an injected `EPartService` where your button is, then pass the Part1's ID to the service to find the part:

```
final MPart part1 = partService.findPart("part1.id");
part1.setToBeRendered(true);
part1.setVisible(true);
```

This snippet creates it if it wasn't there. TBH I don't really know if this grants focus or not.